# group identical rows and fill in NA values

Tags: r

I'm looking for a solution in R to group and combine identical rows in a large table (e.g. 1000 by 300), ignoring NAs (when finding identical rows), to fill in NA values with non NA values from other matching rows. Ultimately creating a consensus for each group. There are also instances where a row can match/belong to multiple groups and should be allocated to all such groups.

for example:

```
data <- rbind(c("A", "A", "B", "C", NA, NA),
              c("A", "A", "B", "NA", NA, NA),
              c("B", "B", "C", "B", NA, NA),
              c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "D", NA),
              c(NA, NA, "B", "C", "D", "D"),
              c("B", NA, NA, NA, NA, "C"),
              c(NA, NA, NA, "B", "D", "C"))

data

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "B"  "C"  NA   NA  
# [2,] "A"  "A"  "B"  "NA" NA   NA  
# [3,] "B"  "B"  "C"  "B"  NA   NA  
# [4,] NA   NA   NA   NA   "D"  NA  
# [5,] NA   NA   "B"  "C"  "D"  "D" 
# [6,] "B"  NA   NA   NA   NA   "C" 
# [7,] NA   NA   NA   "B"  "D"  "C"
```

rows 1,2,4,5 and rows 3,4,6,7 should be grouped to form the 2 following consensuses;

```
# (1,2,4,5) "A" "A" "B" "C" "D" "D"
# (3,4,6,7) "B" "B" "C" "B" "D" "C"
```

I have considered using dplyr group_by, however as there are NA values in the group by columns (all columns) this unfortunately doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why does row 4 go with the first group and not the second one? Oh wait, it does. So these are non-disjoint "groups"? So you should start with rows having the smallest number of value/positions and find all their "matches", then move to the rows with larger numbers of values/positions. I doubt any function would do this out of the box. You probably need  nested for-loops. Looks to be painful.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how or why you chose `1,2,4,5` and `3,4,6,7` but I will just use them to give you the desired results.

```
 A=lapply(apply(data,1,list),unlist)
 t(sapply(list(c(1,2,4,5),c(3,4,6,7)),function(x)coalesce(!!! A[x])))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,] "A"  "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "D" 
 [2,] "B"  "B"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a solution, but I am sure there are others, maybe more efficient methods to achieve the same result.

The following code starts by looking for identical matches between rows. For each row, paired groups are made for each pairwise identical match. Then dplyr is used to merge the 2 rows within each group replacing NAs. The merged rows then replace the rows prior to merging and the process is looped until no further identical matches are found between rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- rbind(c("A", "A", "B", "C", NA, NA),
              c("A", "A", "B", NA, NA, NA),
              c("B", "B", "C", "B", NA, NA),
              c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "D", NA),
              c(NA, NA, "B", "C", "D", "D"),
              c("B", NA, NA, NA, NA, "C"),
              c(NA, NA, NA, "B", "D", "C"))

data <- as_tibble(data)

data
# A tibble: 7 x 6
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     A     A     B     C  <NA>  <NA>
2     A     A     B  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3     B     B     C     B  <NA>  <NA>
4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     D  <NA>
5  <NA>  <NA>     B     C     D     D
6     B  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     C
7  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     B     D     C

merge2x <- function(x, data_ident, data){ #pairwise merging of matching rows

    idx <- which(data_ident[,x]==T) #index of which rows match x
    idx <- idx[-which(idx==x)]

    if(length(idx)!=0){
        grp <- sort(c(1:length(idx),1:length(idx))) #pairwise grp ids
        idx <- as.vector(rbind(x, idx)) #index of pairwise groups of x and every matching row

        data2 <- cbind(grp, data[idx,])

        #use dplyr to merge rows and fill in NAs within groups      
        data2 <- data2 %>%
             group_by(grp) %>%
             summarise_all(funs(first(na.omit(.)))) %>%
             mutate_all(as.character)

        return(data2[!duplicated(data2[,-1]),-1])
    }else{
        return(data[x,])
    }

}


repeat{ #loop merging pairwise matches between rows until now more rows can be merged
    data_ident <- apply(data, 1, function(x) (colSums(!(t(data)==x), na.rm=T)==0 & colSums((t(data)==x), na.rm=T)>=1) ) #logical matrix of which rows are identical

    if(sum(data_ident[lower.tri(data_ident)])==0){
        break
    }
    data2 <- bind_rows(lapply(c(1:ncol(data_ident)), merge2x, data_ident, data))
    data <- data2[!duplicated(data2),]

}

data
# A tibble: 2 x 6
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     A     A     B     C     D     D
2     B     B     C     B     D     C
```